# try-with-resources Statement resource leakage and HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRead() resource leakage

Tags: java, try-with-resources, veracode, resource-leak

In the below code I have used BufferedReader and InputStreamReader inside the try and but veracode complains the security as  `Improper Resource Shutdown or Release (CWE ID 404)`

```
 try (final BufferedReader bsr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Myutils.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("fileName.txt")))) {

            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = bsr.readLine()) != null) {
           // doing some operations
            }

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("exception occurres");
        }
    }
```

Also in another class I am extending HttpServletRequestWrapper

```
public class MyHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        if (null == this.reader) {
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), getCharacterEncoding()));
        }
        return this.reader;
    }

    }
```

here in `this.reader` line veracode giving the  `Improper Resource Shutdown or Release (CWE ID 404)`. I think the framework (tomcat/spring) is handling this. But not sure why veracode saying this.

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream` will be left open if an exception is thrown after opening the `InputStream` but before assigning the `BufferedReader`. In the example you've provided this can only happen if the `InputStreamReader` constructor throws an exception. To avoid this you can use the following code:

```
try (final InputStream is = Example.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.txt");
             final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
             final BufferedReader bsr = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);) {
```

Comment: In my example, If any exception happens in InputStreamReader, InputStream will not be closed. right?

Comment: Yes. If InputStreamReader throws an exception then InputStream may not be closed. If you use the code I provided in my answer then it will be closed properly if there is an exception.